# Set MaterialPropertyBlock color alpha in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, alpha, tween

I am changing the color of a mesh by setting a `MaterialPropertyBlock` like so

```
mpb = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
Color color = Color.red
mpb.SetColor("_Main", color);
_meshRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(mpb);
```

The issue is the color is applied at its 100% intensity. There is no `alpha` property on the color or the `MaterialPropertyBlock`.

Can you suggest how I can make this color change more gradual via an alpha? I would like to tween in and out the red effect instead of it just being 100% on or off (note: I know I am not using a tween here as I would tween the alpha once I know how to set it above).

Update

As per a suggestion from @TEEBQNE I tried setting the alpha in the constructor but even at 0 it showed up at full intensity

```
mpb = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
Color color = new Color(0, 255, 0, 0f); // Still shows 100% color change
mpb.SetColor("_Main", color);
_meshRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(mpb);
```

Update

This issue was shader specific and I had to set another property (specifically the `"_Color"` alpha property). So my general answer is that to add color + alpha will depend on your specific shader and a specific named property.

Comment: Why would there be an alpha property? Color as a property can be rgb or rgba. Simply assign an alpha as the fourth float of a color. `Color newRed = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, a);` Then just twean the alpha float in this new color and apply it.

Comment: Ah so you can set the color in the constructor but not afterwards. I will try this thank you.

Comment: Yep exactly. Let me know if you get it working.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, it seems like the alpha channel is ignored entirely. I tried setting the alpha to 0 before applying and it still shows as 100% intensity.

Comment: Which default shader are you using for this material? It needs to be on the transparency pass. Try Unlit/Transparent. Or try editing the color of your current materials [`albedo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterAlbedoColor.html)

Comment: This is actually a Spine2D shader Spine/Skeleton Tint`  (and my lack of knowledge is criminal). It sounds like this is a shader issue though I will do some digging on this shader and update.

Answer (score 3):

I am unfamiliar with your current shader, but you can change the `RenderMode` of your `Material` to `Transparent` or one of the other alternates to transparency.

[image: Example Transparency]

Once you do that, when you change the [`Albedo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterAlbedoColor.html) alpha channel of your texture, the alpha will change your object.

From the docs, changing the alpha of the albedo

> ...has an effect if the Rendering Mode for the material is set to one
> of the transparent mode, and not Opaque

Comment: The shader I have looks custom and doesnt have those options. I will followup after I find out more. Thank you so far though

Comment: @Aggressor If you post the shader code I might be able to help. I am also not the best with shaders, but setting the render pass to a non-opaque mode is not too difficult once you know where to look.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. It turns out I needed to set a specific property but your questions helped me understand that this issue was specific to my shader not a "general" thing you can do.

Comment: @Aggressor Glad you were able to figure it out!